# Is it possible to require a derived class to implement a virtual method from base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I want a method to do a consistent thing in base class while derived classes can have it do something different (hence it being virtual), while requiring it be implemented in derived classes as if it were abstract. It being required would prevent forgetfulness of implementing it among myself and others working on it.

To break it down (this code is for a Unity project):

```
// Base
public abstract class Attack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual void AttackFinished()
    {
        Entity.StateController.SwitchToState<IdleState>();
    }
}

// Child
public class PlayerSwordAttack : Attack
{
    // I want this implementation to be required, not optional
    // while having it still do the stuff it does in base
    public override void AttackFinished()
    {
        base.AttackFinished();
        // Extra stuff
    }
}
```

In this case, I want `PlayerSwordAttack` or any other child classes to require implementing `AttackFinished()` without it being abstract.

Tl;dr: Essentially I want `public abstract virtual void AttackFinished()` which isn't possible as far as I know, but I hope to learn of a way to do it.

Given that I haven't found this question posted here or anywhere else, I'm expecting the answer to be "don't be silly, it's impossible" but thought I'd ask, since a friend of mine has had the same question.

Comment: Do you also want to "require" that the derived class to always call `base.AttackFinished();`?

Comment: I'm fine with that but I'd be interested in knowing if that can be avoided

Comment: _Essentially I want `public abstract virtual void AttackFinished()`_ - your base code isn’t abstract though as it has the base implementation

Comment: @stuartd Exactly, I'm wondering if it can be both virtual and abstract in some clever way, as you can't have both keywords as virtual requires body but abstract can't have body.

Having it abstract would require child classes to override it, but I want base to run its own code there.

Comment: Related? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/375754/c-design-to-force-the-virtual-method-to-be-called-from-the-override-or-somethi

Comment: Also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c25b6477-b990-4284-abaf-801ddf18207c/force-an-override?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: Yeah those would work, but they're using 2 methods to achieve this, while I was just wondering if it could be done with one method. But I'm guessing not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just break it down into two methods. One is non-virtual, non-abstract, so is not overridable. This will call the abstract method that derived classes are forced to implement.

```
public abstract class Attack
{
    public void AttackFinished()
    {
        Entity.StateController.SwitchToState<IdleState>();
        OnAttackFinished();
    }
    
    protected abstract void OnAttackFinished();
}

public class PlayerSwordAttack : Attack
{
    protected override void OnAttackFinished()
    {
        // Extra stuff
    }
}
```

Note that this is like forcing `base.AttackFinished` in your original code to be called in the derived classes' implementations. If you want derived classes to opt out of this, you can add an additional property:

```
public abstract class Attack
{
    public void AttackFinished()
    {
        if (ShouldChangeStateAfterAttack) {
            Entity.StateController.SwitchToState<IdleState>();
        }
        OnAttackFinished();
    }
    
    protected abstract void OnAttackFinished();
    
    // could also be virtual instead to provide a default implementation
    protected abstract bool ShouldChangeStateAfterAttack { get; }
}

public class PlayerSwordAttack : Attack
{
    protected override void OnAttackFinished()
    {
        // Extra stuff
    }

    protected override bool ShouldChangeStateAfterAttack => false;
}
```

`base.AttackFinished` in your original code could also be called independently, from anywhere in the derived class. If you also want that, simply extract the line `Entity.StateController.SwitchToState<IdleState>();` as another method.